# How to delay code until end of window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
(function () {
    var curImgId = 1;
    var numberOfImages = 4;
    window.setInterval(function() {
        if (matchMedia('(min-width: 1250px)').matches) {
            $('#bg-img').css('background-image','url(../images/background' + curImgId + '.png)');
            curImgId = (curImgId + 1) % numberOfImages;
        }
        else{
            $('#bg-img').css('background-image','url(../images/background_mini' + curImgId + '.png)');
            curImgId = (curImgId + 1) % numberOfImages;
        }
    }, 7 * 1000);
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if (matchMedia('(min-width: 1250px)').matches) {
            $('#bg-img').css('background-image','url(../images/background' + curImgId + '.png)');
            curImgId = (curImgId + 1) % numberOfImages;
        }
        else{
            $('#bg-img').css('background-image','url(../images/background_mini' + curImgId + '.png)');
            curImgId = (curImgId + 1) % numberOfImages;
        }
    });
})();
```

I tried to do animated background but i have a problem. When I resize window images change rapidly. How to fix it. Also i'll be grateful if you improve this code.

Comment: What code do you want to delay exactly? And have you tried executing the code you want to delay inside a `setTimeout` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `matchMedia` you can listen to the `change` event. This event will fire whenever the `matches` state changes in the media query.

In the example below the event will fire whenever the screen changes and `min-width: 1250px` will either match or stop matching.

```
const mediaQuery = matchMedia('(min-width: 1250px)');
mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', ({ matches }) => {
  if (matches) {
    $('#bg-img').css('background-image','url(../images/background' + curImgId + '.png)');
    curImgId = (curImgId + 1) % numberOfImages;
  } else {
    $('#bg-img').css('background-image','url(../images/background_mini' + curImgId + '.png)');
    curImgId = (curImgId + 1) % numberOfImages;
  }
});
```

This allows you to omit the `resize` event because you no longer have to check every time the width changes. The media query will notify you whenever a relevant change happens.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the answer of Emiel is the right question. If I understood, the Filipuer wanna a code that page size stop changing, the Emiel answer is good just for recognize the current media query in the instant of the change, then it will not work for that Fiipeur wanna.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    var initialWindowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (initialWindowWidth == window.innerWidth) {
            functionYouWannaRun();
        }
    }, 100);
})
function functionYouWannaRun() {
    console.log('Resizing is stopped');
}
```

This could help you. Basically, the code check the last width resizing and after 100ms check it again, if the second size is diferente that indicate tha windows still in resizing. If someone resizes too slowly, just increase the time interval value

If I don't got it right, the Emiel probably is the right answer.